# get html source through proxy

Tags: c#, vb.net

Hi how do I get the source of an html page through a proxy. When I use the code below I get an error saying "Proxy Authentication Required." and I have to go through a proxy.

```
Dim client As New WebClient()

Dim htmlCode As String = client.DownloadString("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then use a proxy that does not need authentication

see here for more info
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.proxy.aspx

```
string source = GetPageSource("http://www.stackoverflow.com");

    private string GetPageSource(string url)
    {
        string htmlSource = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            System.Net.WebProxy myProxy = new System.Net.WebProxy("Proxy IP", 8080);
            using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
            {
                client.Proxy = myProxy;
                client.Proxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                htmlSource = client.DownloadString(url);
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        { 
            // log any exceptions
        }
        return htmlSource;
    }
```

Comment: but I have to go through a proxy

Comment: You now only have to convert it to VB.Net but that should be easy

Comment: No Thnx Man!  Glad i could help